# Classpath having issues

Tags: java, servlets

I'm trying to compile a simple servlet program using Command prompt.Im getting error that servlet packages is unknown.This could be due to classpath issues but I couldnt figure out what went wrong in command.

```
E:\Project1>javac -classpath \Servlet\servlet-api.jar -d classes src/Ch1Servlet.
java
src\Ch1Servlet.java:1: error: package javax.servlet does not exist
import javax.servlet.*;
^
```

In environmental variable I have set 'Servlet' variable value as-

```
C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.0-RC5-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.0-RC5\lib
```

What could be the possible reason?I'm a beginner and will really appreciate any help on this.Thanks in advance

Comment: You're hardcoding `Servlet` rather than referring to the environment variable.

Comment: How could I refer to environment variable then?can you please elaborate?

Comment: In Windows, like this: `%Servlet%`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this then. Here `%Servlet%` refers to the value of the environment variable you have defined.

`E:\Project1>javac -classpath %Servlet%\servlet-api.jar -d classes src/Ch1Servlet.java`

Answer (score 0):

Use this line:

```
javac -classpath %Servlet%\servlet-api.jar -d classes src/Ch1Servlet.java
```

`%Servlet%` causes the shell to resolve the environment variable `Servlet` and substitute it with the associated value.